# Android SharedPref not saving on restart

Tags: android, save, sharedpreferences, exit, restart

In my Android app I can display a popup when the app is updated (Based on `versionCode`). In the popup I have put a checkbox saying "dont show me again". When I click on that, it will save in the `sharedpref` the `versionCode` and wont display the popup anymore.

I have run against something odd behaviours where when I have saving the new `Set<String>`, it did indeed was saving it but when my app restarts the settings is lost.

```
Set<String> readAnnouncement = getReadAnnouncement(this);
readAnnouncement.add(String.valueOf(versionCode));   
PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this).edit().putStringSet(KEY_READ_ANN, readAnnouncement).apply();
```

If I break point on `readAnnouncement.add`, I can set for example the list having 2 items. When I execute the `PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPrefer...` and then execute `getReadAnnouncement(this);` the value is there, all good.

If I restart the app and check again `getReadAnnouncement(this);` the new value is gone.

By clearing the cache the problem disappeared... Why was is not saving? Is it possible the `SharedPreference` were full?

Answer (score 0):

Try like this.

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
/**
 * @author VIVEK
 *         This class deals in with setting Cache value for complete app.
 */
public class SharedPrefUtil{

    /*Set Boolean value in shared preferences */
    public static void setSharedPref(Context context, String key, boolean value) {
        // save token in preference
        SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = context.getSharedPreferences("usb", 0);
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();
        editor.putBoolean(key, value);
        editor.commit();
    }

    /*get Boolean value in shared preferences */
    public static boolean getSharedPref(Context context, String key, boolean defaultVal) {
        boolean prefToken = defaultVal;
        SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = context.getSharedPreferences("usb", 0);
        prefToken = sharedPreferences.getBoolean(key, false);
        return prefToken;
    }

    /*Set String value in shared preferences */
    public static void setSharedPref(Context context, String key, String value) {
        // save token in preference
        SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = context.getSharedPreferences("usb", 0);
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();
        editor.putString(key, value);
        editor.commit();
    }

    /*get String value in shared preferences */
    public static String getSharedPref(Context context, String key, String defaultVal) {
        String value = defaultVal;
        SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = context.getSharedPreferences("usb", 0);
        value = sharedPreferences.getString(key, defaultVal);
        return value;
    }

    public static void cleanSharedPrefFile(Context context) {
        // save token in preference
        SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = context.getSharedPreferences("usb", 0);
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();
        editor.clear();
        editor.commit();
    }

} // End of main class over here ...
```

Now you want to set some value in Shared Pref then set like this

```
SharedPrefUtil.setSharedPref(MainActivity.this, "test", storeBuff);
```

Now when you need to get value from shared Pref then call like this

```
SharedPrefUtil.getSharedPref(MainActivity.this, "test", "default value");
```

In place of `editor.commit()` , use `editor.apply()`

**BASICS:**

getDefaultSharedPreferences() uses a default preference-file name. This default is set per application, so all activities in the same app context can access it easily as in the following example:

```
SharedPreferences spref = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
if (spref.contains("email")) {
     String sEmailAddr = spref.getString("email", "");
}
```

The preferences are usually stored at `/data/data/com.package.name/shared_prefs/com.package.name_preferences.xml`

The alternative method - getSharedPreferences(name,mode) requires to indicate a specific preference (file) name and an operation mode (e.g. private, world_readable, etc.), which allow to have better access over your SharedPref file.

Comment: I'm not gonna just gonna copy past blindely some random code without understanding what is the cause of the problem.

Comment: Update complete class over SO

Comment: Sorry I can't accept this. It doesn't answer in anyway to the original question. I don't need code. I need an answer to why the pref get lost after a restart